# FTP using SOCKS 5 C#

Tags: c#

i want to download files from FTP server, for that i need proxy socks5 connection.
When i try to do that, i receive this exMsg:
The underlying connection was closed: the connection was unexpectedly disconnected.

here is my code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_address) as FtpWebRequest;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("#####", ####);
(...)

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

It would be helpfull, if anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: `FtpWebRequest` doesn't support SOCKS5 proxy. There are some other (free/.Net compatible) solutions around. Ask Google (or SO, there are links and examples).

Comment: i tryed with the class WebClient, but it does not working

Comment: do you any othes?